# Get Contact No From PhoneBook In android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contacts, android-logcat, android-cursor

I'm developing a simple app, in which, when I click on **EditText**, **phone contact** will open and when user select a contact, it will be displayed in EditText.
I have done it, but the problem is for some contact it display output like this:

```
05-09 13:39:03.660: D/Actual No--->>>(953): 84 85 835654
05-09 13:39:03.660: D/phoneno(953): Tufan 85 835654
05-09 13:39:08.911: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(953): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-09 13:39:15.428: D/Actual No--->>>(953): 08485835654
05-09 13:39:15.428: D/phoneno(953): Tufan8485835654
05-09 13:39:22.512: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(953): showStatusIcon on    inactive InputConnection
05-09 13:39:31.825: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(953): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-09 13:39:42.468: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(953): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-09 13:45:16.147: D/Actual No--->>>(953): +918485835654
05-09 13:45:16.147: D/phoneno(953): Tufan8485835654
```

So as you can see for some contact it gives me correct result. How to solve this friends?

Check my java code:

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();
Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,
                null, null);
        phones.moveToFirst();
        String phn_no = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
        Log.d("Actual No--->>>", phn_no);
        int len = phn_no.length() % 10;
        String phn_no1 = phn_no.substring(len, phn_no.length());
        Log.d("phoneno", "Tufan" + phn_no1);
    }
}
```

I think problem is in space between number, but its up to user how he saves. But as a programmer, I need to solve. If anyone know, then please help me out.

Comment: so what do you want to do

Answer (score 1):

The code to get the contact number seems Okay.

I guess the trouble is only with the space coming in the contact no.

You can remove that space by replacing -

```
String phn_no = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
```

To

```
String phn_no = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1")).trim().replace(" ","");
```

Hope its helpful. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

try by this code this is running code.

```
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String name = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        System.out.println(name + "==" + phoneNumber);

    }
    phones.close();
```